Define a class (e.g. dataclass or Pydantic BaseModel or TypedDict) whose fields are defined by a collection of strings
Suppose I have a collection of strings defined as a StrEnum:
class ValidNames(StrEnum):
    OLLY = auto()
    ADAM = auto()
    ANNA = auto()

I want to define a class, ideally with Pydantic (for type verification and conversion) that looks like this:
class Assignment(pydantic.BaseModel):
    olly: int = 0
    adam: int = 0
    anna: int = 0


And I want to be able to take external JSON data like this:
external_data = {"olly": 14, "anna": 3}
this_assignment = Assignment(**external_data)

However, I don't want to have to explicitly define the fields of Assignment; I want it to be defined by the values of ValidNames because I don't want to change two bits of code every time the members of ValidNames change (or are added or deleted), and for other reasons. Is there a way to do this, with or without Pydantic?
Basically I just want a dict[ValidNames, pydantic.NonNegativeInt] but as a class (with default value 0 for each field) and not a dict. Ideally a Pydantic class.

This question is similar to: Generate dynamic model using pydantic. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That is somewhat easy() to do with pure Python runtime relevant code - but if you rely on tools that perform static checking, so that the class members can be shown at edit-type/checking time, that is more complicated - I´d go for a two step build process, where the first one generates a Python static file. ( I will trust the existing answers cover the "easy" part)

Pydantic supports dynamic model creation.
from enum import StrEnum, auto
from pydantic import create_model


class ValidNames(StrEnum):
    OLLY = auto()
    ADAM = auto()
    ANNA = auto()


Assignment = create_model(
    'Assignment',
    **{vn.value: (int, 0) for vn in ValidNames}
)


I think this is the closest to the solution I wanted.

You could do something like this:
import pydantic
from enum import StrEnum, auto


class ValidNames(StrEnum):
    OLLY = auto()
    ADAM = auto()
    ANNA = auto()


def AssignmentFactory():
    attrs = {x.value: 0 for x in ValidNames}
    annotations = {x.value: int for x in ValidNames}
    attrs["__annotations__"] = annotations
    return type("Assignment", (pydantic.BaseModel,), attrs)


Assignment = AssignmentFactory()

Now we have an Assignment class that works as you would expect:
>>> a = Assignment()
>>> a
Assignment(olly=0, adam=0, anna=0)
>>> a = Assignment(olly=1, adam=2)
>>> a
Assignment(olly=1, adam=2, anna=0)

(Thanks to this answer for the answer to my question about how to assign type annotations when creating a class with type()!)

Thank you very much. But hmmm that AssignmentFactory() looks like it's cancelling out the elegance of the thing I was imagining in my head LOL.
